# Gitlab runner tags, dynamically choose tag1 OR tag2

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been using Gitlab Pipelines for a while now, and I do understand that

> a runner must be assigned every tag listed in the job

So, the following job requires a runner that has both tags

```
job1:
  tags:
    - tag1
    - tag2
```

However, I am looking for a way to let the job run on a runner with `tag1 OR tag2` rather than `tag1 AND tag2`.

Is that possible without having to assign an additional shared tag to all runners (I don't have access to do so)? And how?

Answer (score 0):

For a runner to be selected to run a job, it must have all of the tags defined in the job.

So in your case the runner must have atleast `tag1` and `tag2` both on it. It can have more tags as well.

This is how the runners are matched. So essentially it does not support the scenario you are looking for(OR condition)